# How can I return two parameters when onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, return

I have a function that returns the currently focused item's ID and a random string. I use a different function to parse through that string.

I need to also return the aria-label, which is where I'm having trouble. None of my current attempts have worked.

```js
var global_focused_id = -1;

function GetLastFocusedId() {
  return global_focused_id;
}

function reply_focus(focused_id) {
  global_focused_id = focused_id + ' || ' + Math.random();
  console.log(global_focused_id);
}
```

```html
<button class="some-class" id="some-id" aria-label="some-label" onfocus="reply_focus(this.id)">Button Text</button>
```

What returns now is:
"*some-id || 0.1234567890*"

What I'd like returned is:
"*some-id || some-label || 0.1234567890*"

Comment: @Mohammednaji what would that look like? in the function? Sorry, I'm still learning the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the entire event (or just the element) and get it from that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```js
var global_focused_id = -1;

function reply_focus(el) {
  global_focused_id = el.id + ' || '
    + el.getAttribute('aria-label') + ' || ' + Math.random();

  console.log(global_focused_id);
}
```

```html
<button class="some-class" id="some-id" aria-label="some-label" 
  onfocus="reply_focus(this)">Button Text</button>
```

Comment: I see the nested logic here. I receive this error, however: "el.getAttribute is not a function". Thanks for taking the time to help a noobie.

Comment: You'd only get that error if no element is passed, or maybe if your variables are mismatched in the function. Are you using it exactly as I have it here?

Answer (score 0):

You have easy access to the element the event handler is bound to -- the Event Object is passed by default:

```
     function eventHandler(event) {... // aka e, evt, etc.
```

The Event property `Event.target` will always reference the tag (element) the user interacted with (ex. user clicked a button now `e.target` points to it). There is also `e.currentTarget` which points to the tag that the event handler is bound to, in the example below the button is both `e.target`, `e.currentTarget`, and `this`.

Note, all values of the button are stored in an object which might be more useful but it isn't necessary. Also [Inline Event Handlers are Garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).
Also read about
[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and
[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

```js
let cfg = {};

function getBtnID(event) {
  const focalPt = event.target;
  
  cfg.id = focalPt.id;
  cfg.key = Math.random();
  cfg.label = this.getAttribute('aria-label');
  
  console.log(cfg);
};
  
document.getElementById('exit-0').addEventListener('focus', getBtnID);

// OR document.getElementById('btn').onfocus = getBtnID;
```

```html
<button id="exit-0" class="btn" aria-label="close">❌</button>
```